# Change data values in instance variable when component loading in vue

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5

I use Vue router for loading components in Laravel.I want to change 'show' value in instance variable when I click router-link.How can I do do this?

```
<router-link to="/login">Login</router-link>
```

Instance Variable:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
        return {
            show: true
        }
    },
    router
});
```

Login Component :

```
<template>
  <div>Login component</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:
`<router-link to="/login" @click.native="show = false">Login</router-link>`

Comment: i solved this.the correct answer is @click.native="show".thanks